# Programming a software for diagnosing SAE J1939

Tags: can-bus, j1939

I'm trying to program a software similar to [this](http://www.pfdiagnose.com/)

Where could I find specific information on the programming language used, the required environment, etc?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at [BUSMASTER](https://github.com/rbei-etas/busmaster) as a reference? This tools supports J1939 packet dissection as also some more extended features and it is Open Source.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some money to spend, check out the [PCAN-USB device](http://www.peak-system.com/PCAN-USB.199.0.html?L=1). Using this device you can write your own program using their [API](http://www.peak-system.com/PCAN-Basic.239.0.html?&L=1), which is supported on most major languages, or getting a license for their PCAN-Explorer software whichever you prefer. I believe versions 5.4 and up have a J1939 plugin that you can get.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different hardware devices and create your code in visual studio or other vendor applications such as CANoe or CANAlyzer.

Hardware:
PCAN
Kvazer
IXXAT USB-to-CAN FD
CANcase
VN1610
or create your own CAN to USB gateway design.
All the available hardware supports different development platforms so it will depends on how much time/money you want to expend.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Vector CAN interfaces as the hardware, I suggest you review the [Vector XL API](https://www.vector.com/int/en/products/products-a-z/libraries-drivers/xl-driver-library/), which you can use for free. Vector XL API is primarily intended to be used with the C# programming language.